# Time between flights in Ministro Pistarini Airport (Buenos Aires)

Tags: buenos-aires, missed-flights, eze

I have 2h40 between two international flights at *Ministro Pistarini Airport*, in Buenos Aires. Am I screwed?

Coming from Santiago and going to Brazil, both flights are in Terminal A.

The tickets are from different companies (coming with *Qantas* via *LAN*, going with *United* via *Turkish*).

Comment: Are they on the same ticket, or different tickets? (Makes a big difference to the risk of problems)

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot about that!

Comment: What are the on-time stats like for your inbound Qantas flight? And if there's enough of a delay that means you can't make the onward flight, how much of an issue is that?

Comment: I don't know about the stats, where can I find that? If I lose that flight it would be very bad since these flights are already too expensive.

Comment: You are right, it's Qantas via LAN.

Comment: I think you've answered it yourself then. It won't take that much of a delay on your inbound to cause you massive problems, so you probably want to give yourself more time to avoid stress+cost in case of any issues

Comment: @Roberto any update? Have you taken the flight and did you have success?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this may be my personal experience, it can help others, so I'm posting the answer to my own question.

It all worked out well. I had plenty of time to do everything. I even had a problem with one of my luggage that was lost in Santiago, I had time to wait a lot for it and to register a complain with the company.

It's not a very big airport, 2h40 is enough unless everything goes wrong for you.

Comment: Both times I arrived there there were terrible queues at customs. The first time in 2011 it took me about 2 hours from plane to the curb, the second time in 2012, it took about 1 1/2 hours. Hopefully that has changed since then.